# d3.js fixed x,y coords for some nodes in force

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, networking

I'm new with d3.js.
I have a disjointed network, it means, in a same file I have many small network like:

```
a a
a b
a c
b a
b b
b c
c a
c b
c c
e e
e f
e g
f e
f f
f g
g e
g f
g g
```

In this example, has two disjointed networks, one has `[a,b,c]` nodes other`[e,f,g]` nodes.

I may tag only one node per network to be my "hub" (not a hub itself necessarily, hubs are highly connected) or "chosen" just inserting `1` if it is chosen or `0` if it is not.

Now the problem is:
"In a force directed graph how do I keep fixed the hubs?".

Actually, what I really would like is, distribute in the space all networks, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, from largest to smallest (in number of nodes).

What did I think. Take only the hubs and assign the `x` and `y` coords and `if (d.choose == 1){ //returns x,y}else{ //free coords}`.

The problem isn't create `x` and `y` columns, but the d3.js code itself to keep some choords frozen.

Follow my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- width="2480" height="1720 -->
<svg width="2600" height="1020"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
  radius = 6;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    // One thing to consider is the overall strength, negative spaced, positive agglomerates
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength( function(d){
    if ( d.choose == 1 ) { return -2;}
    if ( d.choose == 0 ) { return -0.2;  } } ) )
    // Another issue is the distance + distance more distant the dots,
    // d is the jason file, here it is accessing the d.id and d.line
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().iterations(10).id(function(d) {
                                          return d.id; }
                                          ).distance(function (d) {if (d.line == "none"){
        return 15;}
        else {
            return 15;
        }
    }))
    // center graph
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

// load json file (?)
d3.json("genomes_net.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);



// draw line for each pair
  var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        // line color
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {return d.colorsamp;})
        // draw lines (% of total, or gradient?)
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);



// draw circles for each node
    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", (d) => {
            if (d.choose == 0 ) {return 8;}
            if (d.choose == 1) {return 16;}
        })
        //.style("fill", "#FF69B4") //function(d) { return d.colorsamp; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.colorsamp ; })
        .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));
        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return (d.name+ "\n" + d.lineage + " (" + d.genera +")"); });


var text = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
        if (d.direto == "yes"){
            return d.id;
        }

    })
    .attr("font-size", "8px")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("dx", 15)
    .attr("dy", ".31em")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);


  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
    text
        .attr("dx", function (d) {return d.x -20; })
        .attr("dy", function (d) {return d.y + 15; })
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
// Important notes:
// Understanding forces: https://bl.ocks.org/steveharoz/8c3e2524079a8c440df60c1ab72b5d03
//
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Aureliano. I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide an image of what you would like to achive. Also I would like to guide you to the abusing the force talk which really goes into detail about how to split nodes into categories or regions https://vallandingham.me/abusing_the_force.html